# Filling arrays of coordinates to fit a new size, without changing the format of the curve

Tags: c#

Let's say I have an Array of 100 length called rawData, this is the input array of my function.
This function returns me a least squares polynomial fit, but, the size of this return array is smaller, let's say 46 length.
Is there a way for me to insert some data among the returned array so it will be the same in length as the rawData array and still have the save wave format?

To give some background here is an image I get from the program.
[image]

Here, the blue line is the raw data, and the red one is the pollyfit, note that the red line has the same format as the blue one as if it was a small version of it until it suddenly become a lots of zeros. What I want is to get rid of those zeroes or NaN values and make some sort of stretch on the red graph.

I'm not sure if I was clear enough, any extra information that you need please leave a comment.

Comment: So basically the red line goes like `double[] data = { 100, 110, ..., 120, 0,0,0,0,0,0,0....,0}` you want to get rid of the trailing zeroes or NaNs? What about the x-value though (i.e. the scaling)? Is every data point accomponied by a x-value? You'd have to stretch them (with a constant factor) too.

Comment: @MaximilianGerhardt I don't know if that would do it for me. The x values are represented by the position of the Y values in the array. the matter is that scalling it would just make the points farther from each other, and I need that both arrays have the same size (Count).

Comment: Then wouldn't this already be enough? `var cleanedData = data.TakeWhile( y_val => !Double.IsNaN(y_val));` and plotting these values? Alternatively scan the array from right to left for zeroes/nans and make up your own `List<double>`.

Comment: @MaximilianGerhardt Either I didn't understand what you said or you didn't understand what I said. If I do what you are saying my cleanedData.Count will be smaller than my rawData.Count, and they must be the same.

Comment: That's why I asked about the x-Value. First of all, give all your y-Values an x-Value (`double[] pData = { 10, 12, 13,}` becomes `Point[] pPoints = { new Point(0,10), new Point(1,12), new Point(2,13)}`), then cut of the points as I said, then compensate for the stretching by multiplying the x-coordinate with the constant (`double c = sizeBefore - sizeAfter`). If you plot these set of points, since they now have the right x-coordinates, they will be plotted correctly as you want.

Comment: @MaximilianGerhardt Thanks a lot, I get it now, i'm going to try it.